# Merging a few separately trained skikit-learn MLPRegressor models into one

Tags: scikit-learn

I am thinking about parallel training a few MLPRegressor models using individual subset of training data (or maybe random selection from same test data) and then somehow "merge" individually trained model into one, presumable better trained. 
Is any official way to do it?  If no - what could be hack? I am not familiar with MLPRegressor internals but from common sense I should average same weights from separate models and put those averages into final model. Any more ideas?

Comment: Why would you like to do this? Neural networks have their own methods for regularization and deal with the stuff you describe on their own. Sure, you can always average the predictions. Averaging the weights is pointless as you'd be averaging completely unrelated weights.

Comment: No, I am not going to average "unrelated" weights. The idea is - loop across models and for each link (weight) average values it end up in individual models.

Comment: The weights are redundant and randomly initialized, so weight number 5 from model A has nothing to do with weight number 5 in model B.

Comment: You're saying that due to random initialization, different trained models could end up with "logically similar" but physically very different weights?  Makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you are proposing is referred to as an *ensemble*.

For this you can use a `VotingClassifier` with *voting='hard'* or *voting='soft'*. 
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier.html

Comment: Note that `VotingClassifier` cannot reuse already trained models.